# jQuery: Select elements of class X that have no siblings with that class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to only select elements that match class X and don't have *any* siblings that also have class X. In my case, `X = hasDatepicker`. Here's what I've come up with:

```
$('.hasDatepicker:not(.hasDatepicker ~ .hasDatepicker)')
```

However, this does not exclude the first element, so in any group of datepickers, this will still select the first one. I don't want to include any that are in a group, only the singles.

Example with **1** Match:

```
<div class="input text">
<input name="data[Goal][date_started]" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" style="display: none; ">
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/themed/mocha/images/btn_calendar.png" alt="..." title="..."></button>
</div>
```

Example with **0** Matches:

```
<div class="input text">
<input type="text" value="" id="GoalDateStarted" class="hasDatepicker"><input type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" style="display: none; ">
<input type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" style="display: none; ">
<input name="data[Goal][date_started]" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" style="display: none; ">
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/themed/mocha/images/btn_calendar.png" alt="..." title="..."></button>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML structure and what elements you want to match?

Comment: So what element are you looking to select based on your example, the parent div or the input with the hasDatepicker class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not that elegant but it does the trick using the [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) pseudo-selector and filtering the result set with [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

- `:first-child` will help select only the first .test element of a possible multiple siblings list
- use `.filter()` to actually check if there are no siblings with the same class

Here's the code:

```
var a = $('.test:first-child').filter(function() {
    //return $(this).parent().find('.test').not(this).length == 0;
    return !$(this).siblings('.test').length
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vAkuj/)**

Comment: return `!$(this).siblings('.text').length` instead

Comment: It just maks sense to use .siblings() indeed. Thanks !

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue, but this won't work if there is some other element which is the first sibling.  If it's a problem, just remove the `:first-child` part.